# Path for Custom Module in Openerp 7.0

Tags: module, customization, odoo

my OpenERP 7.0 is install in `d:\openERP 7.0` on windows 7. I have copied a custom module to `D:\OpenERP 7.0\Server\server\openerp\addons`, but when I update module list I am unable to see my custom module.

I have tried advanced search options with filters 'extra' and 'not installed' but still no success.

```
<data>

    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="notebook_tree_view">

        <field name="name">notebook.tree</field>

        <field name="model">notebook</field>

        <field name="type">tree</field>

        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <tree string="Notebook">

                <field name="title"/>

                <field name="note"/>

                <field name="note_date"/>

            </tree>

        </field>

    </record>


    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="notebook_form_view">

        <field name="name">notebook.form</field>

        <field name="model">notebook</field>

        <field name="type">form</field>

        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <form string="Notebook">

                <field name="title"/>

                <field name="note"/>

                <field name="note_date"/>

            </form>

        </field>

    </record>


    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_notebook_form">

        <field name="name">notebook</field>

        <field name="res_model">notebook</field>

    </record>

    <menuitem id="notebook_menu"
        name="Notebook"
        icon="terp-project"
    />


    <menuitem id="notebook_menu_mainform"
        name="Notes"
        action="action_notebook_form"
        parent="notebook_menu"
    />

</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

try debugging this way :

1)  Install another addons module and see if you can do
that. If you cannot do that then you are probably putting it
in the wrong directory.

You should have 3 directors one for the server , addons and web

2) If the above goes well then its your module which has 
the problem. Double check your *openerp*.py file

Comment: Thanks Vishal, after some search on google i have been able to install the module. After installation when i click on the main menu (Notebook) of the module it displays the sub menu (Notes) but it is inactive, can you please help identify the problem? i have attached the notebook_view.xml. thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the form views you need to add an attribute `version='7.0'`
For example

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="notebook_form_view">
    <field name="name">notebook.form</field>
    <field name="model">notebook</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="Notebook" version="7.0">
        <field name="title"/>
        <field name="note"/>
        <field name="note_date"/>
    </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Also dont test the module in the old gtk client. openerp 7 doesnt have a gtk client